# Which vim options should be used in modelines?

Tags: vim, modeline

I'm wondering which vim options *should* I be specifying in modelines in my source files (mostly C), and which *should not* be specified there and rather left for the user to specify.

I believe that the modelines should enforce code-specific policies and/or help vim with the code, while avoiding interfering with user preferences if possible.

When answering, *please* explain why you believe that a particular option should be enforced via modeline, or not.

Answer (score 1):

Right now, I find the following options useful:

- `ft` to ensure that vim recognizes the file format correctly,
- `noet` and `sts=0` to disable expanding tabs into spaces (project coding style),
- or alternatively `et`, `ts`, `sts` and `sw` to enforce project-specific tab expansion,
- maybe `tw` to suggest line wrapping (but I wouldn't be so sure about that as it is a bit *intrusive*),
- `fenc` to indicate the character encoding.

And those are the options I believe I shouldn't be setting:

- `ts` if the project uses tab-indent — I believe that the user should be able to choose his own tab width,
- folding — user preference,
- indenting — user may have a preferred way of doing indents and changing that may actually cause extra or missing indent out of habit,
- `ff` because vim should deduce the newline format correctly and if some software (like VCS) transparently converts the file, `ff` will actually break it.